# When is calculating or variable-reading faster?

Tags: programming-languages, performance

to be honest, I don't really know what the "small green men" in my cpu and compiler do, so I sometimes would like to know :).

Currently I would like to know what's faster, so that I can design my code in a more efficient way.
So for example I want to calclate something at different points in my sourcecode, when will it be faster to calculate it once and store it in a variable that's read and used for the next points it's needed and when is it faster to calculate it everytime?

I think it's depending on how "complex" and "long" the calculation is and how fast then cache is, where variables are stored, but I don't have any clue what's faster :).

Thanks for any reply to my tiny but important question!

Andreas

PS: perhaps it's important to know that I code in JAVA, but it's more a genral question.

Comment: If you are interested in this, you could read The Art of Assembly by Randall Hyde at http://homepage.mac.com/randyhyde/webster.cs.ucr.edu/index.html , I hear it's quite good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It will generally *always* be faster to store something calculated once, rather than calculate it each time, unless the calculation is minor and/or the number of times you use it is low.

In other words, it depends entirely on the usage patterns. Consider, for example, the two extremes below.

- The calculation is a adding two numbers together and you only use the result twice.
- The calculation is a monstrous Physics calculation involving the interaction of 47 separate sub-atomic particles, and you use it in three different places in your code, one of which uses it inside a loop with 314,159,265 iterations.

Obviously, you won't get much (or possibly any) benefit from calculating it once in the first example but you're *extremely* likely to benefit by doing so for the second case.

As a general rule, you should first write your code for functionality and readability, and then only worry about performance if it becomes an issue.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure... it wouldn't surprise me if probabilistic primality testing were faster than file IO ;)

Comment: I think this is not true. It depends on from what memory you have to read. I would prefer to sum 3+2+1 a million times rather than storing it in a std::vector!

Comment: When the calculation is small, defining a variable can make a program significantly slower. Try `print(timeit("type(1 + 1); type(1 + 1)"))` vs `print(timeit("a = 1 + 1; type(a); type(a)"))` *(with `from timeit import timeit` of course)*.

Comment: @AnnZen: with a million iterations of that, I got `0.0882` vs. `0.0913`.  So yes, 3.5% slower for the variable one. However, should realise that your `timeit` is including the `a = 1 + 1` *multiple* times . If, as the question requests (calculate once and use many times), you compare `print(timeit("for i in range(1000): type(1 + 1)"))` and `print(timeit("a = 1 + 1\nfor i in range(1000): type(a)"))`, you'll find the variable one is actually *faster* (on my box, calculate = 45.1s, variable = 43.6s).

Comment: However, that's just *one* sample, Python with a very specific use. Things may be vastly different in different languages and different ways of using the data. That's why I included things like "generally" and "depending on" in my answer.

Comment: *"you should realise that your `timeit` is including the a = 1 + 1 multiple times"* Sure I know. But do realize that your `range()` example expects a program to use a variable 1000 times, while I intentionally only used the variable twice *(that is still a reasonable amount of times a calculation has to be made)*.

Comment: I didn't include `number=1` in the `timeit` call as I didn't think it was necessary to prove a point, but let's just say I meant trying `print(timeit("type(1 + 1); type(1 + 1)", number=1))` vs `print(timeit("a = 1 + 1; type(a); type(a)", number=1))`.

Comment: *"But depending on the complexity of the calculation, it may not matter."* Yes, but you failed to include that storing a calculation in a variable may also slow down the program. This caught my attention as I've been working on some pretty high CPU consuming programs, and am doing my best to keep the code as efficient as possible, and that includes figuring out in many places whether defining a variable to store a calculation slows down the program or speeds it up.

Comment: @AnnZen, it sounds like we agree (re the fact that it's very dependent on the usage pattern) but that I was missing a clearer statement on that. Hence I have modified the answer to hopefully clarify that and provide more concrete examples of the two ends of the usage spectrum. You are indeed correct that there's not really much to be gained if you have a simple calculation and only use it twice but I thought I'd better mention the timing disparity since the default count is a million, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The only time I can think of in which it would automatically be slower is if you stored the value in a file, or in a table (e.g. a database).  Then it *could* be slower to retrieve it than to recalculate it.  That does not seem to apply in your case, but you said it was a general question.

But you seem to be dancing around another question -- is it better to use lots of globally stored values.  If that is part of your question, then my answer does not address it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, in situations where this matters, the compiler is smart enough to see it by himself. I am talking about the JIT compiler which lurks in the JVM. That compiler is known to be able to inline method calls and the like.

Also, the general advice is to write *clear* code and to worry about such low-level optimizations only when:

- the code is correct (it yields the expected result);
- there is an actual, measurable problem of performance;
- algorithms are fine (e.g. you are not using a quadratic sort or something like that).

At that point, you have all that you need to *measure* the impact of using an intermediate variable, and that's good, because the answer to your question is, in all generality: "well, it depends."

Answer (score 1):

There's no real answer to this question. It's quicker to store things in the cache if cache accesses are quicker than calculation. It's quicker to calculate things if cache accesses are slower than your calculation.

As with all "which is faster" questions, the answer is to profile, then profile again, and then profile again. Is your calculation really the bottleneck, or are you waiting on I/O somewhere? Try things and see!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should code whatever is most readable and maintainable, and only start looking at performance once you've got it working AND found that it's too slow. There's no point optimising something that runs just fine.

Since calculating something once and saving the result is more maintainable (if the calculation changes, you only need to change it one place) you should do that. Repeating yourself in code is bad.

You'll find that it's faster to do this as well. I can't think of any sensible situation in which it wouldn't be at least as fast to retrieve the pre-calculated result as compared with re-calculating.

Comment: You can find code to be too slow before it's working.  And you can see some (a lot) of performance bottle necks before you get too far into a project.  For example... if you have the option between batch processing requests over a remote process (or connection) this will be faster than making each request separately.  This is typically due to protocol overhead, latency, bandwidth and serialization.  You can even have these issues with reading from files, ports, and devices.

Comment: @Matthew - beware statements like "this will be faster". Who knows? Profile, profile, profile.

Comment: Feel free to yell at me for "pre-optimizing", but I have been working with electronics, networks, and computers long enough to identify some bottle necks before they are an issue.  Just looking at some code screams "I am a problem".  After you get the results back from the profiler you still need to find the solution to the problem.  And the earlier you find that... the less it costs.

Comment: @Matthew - absolutely - but I'd argue that failure to batch requests over a remote connection is a failure in the design rather than the code?

Comment: And a design feature that lots of developers miss.

Answer (score 1):

It should be faster to retrieve over re-calculate but you risk slipping into premature micro-optimization, by deciding different techniques without any instrumentation / measurement that it would make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would say calculating it once and storing in it.

In the example above, you are not likey to be adding static values together all of the time. The values you will be calculating are most likely going to be other variables stored in memory/on disk.

So if you

1. gather all your variables
2. calculate the result
3. store it in memory

From here on in you will only need to retrieve the value, rather than repeat steps 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Caching is generally faster for any computation that is even somewhat complex, but there's a trade-off involved. By caching the results of your computation, you have to take some responsibility for *invalidating* the cache when the result of the computation is no longer accurate. Take the following example:

```
public class Rectangle
    private int _height;
    public int getHeight() {
        return _height;
    }
    public void setHeight(int value) {
        _height = value;
    }

    private int _width;
    public int getWidth() {
        return _width;
    }
    public void setWidth(int value) {
        _width = value;
    }

    private int _area;
    public int getArea() {
        if (_area == 0) {
            _area = _width * height;
        }
        return _area;
    }
}
```

Here, the area calculation is stored so it doesn't need to be recomputed (this is a bit of a trivial example, and multiplications aren't really costly enough to justify caching, but you get the drift.). The following code works fine:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
r.setHeight(5);
r.setWidth(5);

r.getArea(); // returns 25.
```

But if we modify any of the information used to calculate the cached item, the code has a bug:

```
r.setHeight(3);
r.getArea(); // returns 25 - should be 15!
```

In this case the solution is easy - reset the area whenever height or width is set. But if your calculations become more complex, the calculations depend on something outside a single class, or your caching mechanism is more complex than a simple member variable, it can become somewhat troublesome to manage your caches.

In general, whenever you decide you want to use caching, you should proceed with caution and unit test heavily to ensure you're not introducing bugs.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents. I'm thinking in a web medium. Calculation doesn't require server space or data transmition more than the equation itself, which can contain a potential infinite amount of numbers (a fixed rule, for example, factors of 6)

**Please note:** not a coder myself, by the way. So, this may be totally worng :)